# How to remove Navigation's "Delete" button in WinUI2

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

I modified the WinUI2.7 code according to the official documentation(XAML Controls Gallery), but I want to remove the "Settings" button at the bottom of the page.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJODM.png)

Here is my code below.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Mica.MainPage"
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Mica"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
muxc:BackdropMaterial.ApplyToRootOrPageBackground="True"
>
<Page.Resources>
    <!--This top margin is the height of the custom TitleBar-->
    <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="AppTitleBar"
            IsHitTestVisible="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Background="Transparent"
            Height="40"
            Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
            Margin="6,5,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle"
                Text="在鹿山 for Windows"
                VerticalAlignment="center"
                Margin="12, 0, 0, 0"
                Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <muxc:NavigationView x:Name="nvSample">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="主页" Tag="HomePage" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact2" Content="教务相关" Tag="jiaowu" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="OutlineStar" Content="校园生活" Tag="CampusLife" />
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <muxc:NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Content="关于应用" Tag="About" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Mail" Content="反馈/建议" Tag="Feedback" />
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Content="帮助中心" Tag="Help" />
        </muxc:NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </muxc:NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x804 上介绍了“空白页”项模板

namespace Mica
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 可用于自身或导航至 Frame 内部的空白页。
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;

            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
            titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

            // Hide default title bar.
            var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
            coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
            UpdateTitleBarLayout(coreTitleBar);

            // Set XAML element as a draggable region.
            Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);

            // Register a handler for when the size of the overlaid caption control changes.
            // For example, when the app moves to a screen with a different DPI.
            coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;

            // Register a handler for when the title bar visibility changes.
            // For example, when the title bar is invoked in full screen mode.
            coreTitleBar.IsVisibleChanged += CoreTitleBar_IsVisibleChanged;

            //Register a handler for when the window changes focus
            Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
        }

        private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
        {
            UpdateTitleBarLayout(sender);
        }

        private void UpdateTitleBarLayout(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar)
        {
            // Update title bar control size as needed to account for system size changes.
            AppTitleBar.Height = coreTitleBar.Height;

            // Ensure the custom title bar does not overlap window caption controls
            Thickness currMargin = AppTitleBar.Margin;
            AppTitleBar.Margin = new Thickness(currMargin.Left, currMargin.Top, coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset, currMargin.Bottom);
        }

        private void CoreTitleBar_IsVisibleChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar sender, object args)
        {
            if (sender.IsVisible)
            {
                AppTitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                AppTitleBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        // Update the TitleBar based on the inactive/active state of the app
        private void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush defaultForegroundBrush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["TextFillColorPrimaryBrush"];
            SolidColorBrush inactiveForegroundBrush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["TextFillColorDisabledBrush"];

            if (e.WindowActivationState == Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
            {
                AppTitle.Foreground = inactiveForegroundBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                AppTitle.Foreground = defaultForegroundBrush;
            }
        }

        // Update the TitleBar content layout depending on NavigationView DisplayMode
        private void NavigationViewControl_DisplayModeChanged(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewDisplayModeChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            const int topIndent = 16;
            const int expandedIndent = 48;
            int minimalIndent = 104;

            // If the back button is not visible, reduce the TitleBar content indent.
            Thickness currMargin = AppTitleBar.Margin;

            // Set the TitleBar margin dependent on NavigationView display mode
            if (sender.PaneDisplayMode == Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.Top)
            {
                AppTitleBar.Margin = new Thickness(topIndent, currMargin.Top, currMargin.Right, currMargin.Bottom);
            }
            else if (sender.DisplayMode == Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewDisplayMode.Minimal)
            {
                AppTitleBar.Margin = new Thickness(minimalIndent, currMargin.Top, currMargin.Right, currMargin.Bottom);
            }
            else
            {
                AppTitleBar.Margin = new Thickness(expandedIndent, currMargin.Top, currMargin.Right, currMargin.Bottom);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made all these changes based on the official application XAML Controls Gallery, but this is not in the documentation results, but I encountered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavigationView` control has an `IsSettingsVisible` property that you can set to `false` to hide the "Settings" button:

```
<muxc:NavigationView x:Name="nvSample" IsSettingsVisible="False">
...
```